# cartthrob on multisite

Tags: cartthrob, multi-site-manager

can cartthrob installed on MSM site ?  I have try to using cartthrob on multi site, but the item data on cart not all shown ( just the product title ). Please help me to solve this problem . Thanks before.

Comment: after upgrading cartthrob to the latest version , i finally found the answer. Cartthrob Pro 2.5 has this settings => Show all Order/Product Channels from MSM sites, this settings enable us to use channel from other site in MSM. Thanks